# How to strip an individual list item (string)?

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

I have a line like the following:

```
ping = subprocess.call('Fping.exe -H %s -L pingResults.txt -l' % 'IPsToPING')
```

Where `IPsTPING` is a list, my problem is that it returns the IPs inside that list with `[` (just the first IP and the last one with `]`) and single quotes around each IP like that:

`'192.168.1.1'`

The problem is that Fping.exe is failing to do its work since it gets an IP address with quotes.

I would like to somehow stripe these quotes from every IP (or list item), and the `[` `]` from the first and the last items.

I am using Python 3.x.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the list of IPs yourself:

```
ip_string = ",".join(IPsToPING)
subprocess.call('Fping.exe -H %s ...' % ip_string)
```

(assuming a comma-separated list is what you want).

Comment: Isn't that would create just a long string?

Comment: @HananN.: did you try it?  It creates one long string, without quotes or brackets, with commas separating your IP addresses.